# MVC Sending localPath to Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm a complete newbie to MVC so any tips etc will go a long way, just trying to pass back the current url that the user it on but having no luck. Code being used is below.

```
Controller    

public string AddMini(TodoMini todo)
{
    return todo.URL;
}
```

---

```
View

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMini", "ToDo", FormMethod.Post)){
    <li>
        @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.URL, Request.Url.LocalPath)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Add To-Do items", @autocomplete = "off" })
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

Hopefully that's enough to see the problem.

Cheers guys

Comment: What is in the HTML when you see this view? What gets posted to the controller?

Comment: the hidden looks like <input length="16" id="URL" name="URL" type="hidden" value=""> in HTML. The post has the values set in the controller when running debug, but the URL is set as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the Url from the Request instead of receiving it in the model?

```
public string AddMini(TodoMini todo)
{
    var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
    //Rest of the POST logic
}
```

Comment: That's giving me "/ToDo/AddMini" which is the response url rather than the requesting url. It should be sending something like "/Property/Edit/3" hope that makes sense

Comment: OK, I see. I thought the GET and POST requests were made to the same URL.

Comment: I'm doing it through a partial

Answer (score 0):

use

In my controller

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var todo = new TodoMini() {URL = Request.Url.LocalPath};
        return View(todo);
    }
```

And in View

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.URL)
```

Should work, make sure that correct value is assigned to Url property, local path will only return path after **hostname**. in my case it is returning **/Home/** if I use l**ocalhost:3934/Home**  and if just **locahhost:port/** then returns **"/"**

In case you don't want to add Url to your model then you should create a ViewModel class which should contain all the property you are using inside your view.

Comment: This makes more sense but it's in a partial which doesn't use an Index() which is why I'm trying to add to the hidden.

Comment: Request object should be available in any view. it's problem in the way @Html.HiddenFor you are using.

Comment: As I added to my answer you can always use ViewModel for particular view and populate that in controller and pass that viewmodel to view.